# How to add the username when reporting a Non-Fatal Error?

Tags: android, crashlytics

I'm using the `Crashlytics.logException()` method when I want to programmatically report a [non-fatal error](http://support.crashlytics.com/knowledgebase/articles/202805-logging-caught-exceptions) on Crashlytics.

Although I set up a valid identifier for the current logged user when the application starts, with `Crashlytics.setUserName()`, I can't see this information in the dashboard. Instead, it appears only when there is a crash (see picture).

[image]

How can I enable it for non-fatal errors too?

**EDIT:** I'm using Crashlytics plugin for Eclipse, 1.7.0

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38231199/2528850

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved this simply by updating the Crashlytics library.

I still had the 1.7.0 version, without Fabric. I upgraded the account and I downloaded the new 2.0 package using [the new guide](https://fabric.io/downloads/eclipse) and now I can see the user's information in all the non-fatal errors.

Answer (score 4):

The username info will appear at non-fatal crashes too. Can you please check if the call to `Crashlytics.setUsername()` is being done before the `Crashlytics.logException()`?

See the screenshot below:

[image: screenshot]

However, the logging of messages are currently not synchronously, so if the crash occurs quickly, all or none of these statements can make it over. The writing of the data is done in a background thread, so the crash that is processing will always trump the other thread, so in this case, the crash will always trump when the log is bring written even though it might've started up first.

Comment: I call `setUserName()` right after the user is initialized, at startup. Obviously, `logException()` might be called later unexpectedly, but I assume that the information about the user have not been forgotten by Crashlytics.

Comment: thanks for pointing this, I edited the answer with an explanation

Comment: Thanks but this doesn't explain very much the cause of my problem, because between `setUserName()` and the call to `logException()` may pass, for example, 2 minutes. It's certainly a reasonable time... but the information is still not present in the report!